React Native - Could not get unknown property 'com' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension
I'm updating my react native project with targetSdkVersion 34, I ran into the security error (I followed the steps listed but I'm still getting the error) so I decided to update some of my libraries so that they were compliant to Android 14 rules. I was updating react-native-device-info to the latest version v11.1.0, then while building it in Android Studio i get the following error.
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-device-info'.
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'com' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension.

The line in question is in the build.gradle file in react-native-device-info
def agpVersion = com.android.Version.ANDROID_GRADLE_PLUGIN_VERSION
I'm not sure what I can do about this.
My react-native version - react-native@0.60.5
